# How does this app use encrypted/hashed data from scanned barcodes to display identification information?

Tags: reverse-engineering, barcode, pdf417

[image: The barcode in question]I came across an app that has a feature where it scans PDF417 barcodes and brings up identification information for each person. When I scanned the barcode, it provided a string like 'AT6Om0nTmES4r0RpLEoQguf/bD7gL01E+ZdRAfvLQtV7.' I'm curious about how the app uses this string to display the full identification information. Could this be encrypted data? Or is it a hash value? How does the app process this data to show the relevant details on the identification page?
I'd appreciate any insights or explanations on the backend processes involved in handling this data.

Answer (score 0):

This barcode only contains about 32 bytes of actual data. You don't give any details about the *"full identification information"*. But most likely that is far too short to contain the actual data.

So most likely it is some sort of ID used to look up the full information online.